# Assembly call interrupt based on register value

Tags: assembly, x86, interrupt

I would like to have an interrupt in NASM that calls not a hard-coded interrupt but an int. in a register.
To give you an example:

```
mov al, 0x10
int al    ; you can't do this for some reason
```

So if I stored 0x10 in register al then I could call an interrupt based on what is in that register.

Is there any way I could do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there any way I could do this?

**In 16-bit "Real Mode" without self-modifying code:**

Most C compilers for DOS provided a library function that allowed to perform the equivalent of `int al`.

This worked the following way:

In real mode an `int` instruction is equal to a `pushf` followed by a far `call` to the interrupt handler.

However, a "far" `call` is nothing but pushing the "far" address (`cs` and `ip`) of the next instruction on the stack and performing a jump. (A "near" call only pushes `ip`.) A `retf` will pop `ip` and `cs` from the stack and jump to that address.

The address of the interrupt handler is stored at the address 0:(4*n).

So to enter an interrupt, you first perform the following code:

```
  pushf
  push cs       # Leave this line out if "call helper" is a "far" call
  call helper
```

When entering the function `helper`, the stack looks like this:

```
Address (IP) of the instruction after "call helper"
Segment (CS) of the program
Flags
...
```

These three elements are on the stack after an `int` instruction.

The program `helper` looks like this.

```
helper:
    # Calculate BX = 4*AX
    # (This can be done with less instructions on a modern CPU)
  mov bl,al
  mov bh,0
  add bx,bx
  add bx,bx
    # Set DS to 0
  xor ax,ax
  mov ds,ax
    # Push the segment part of the interrupt handler address
    # to the stack
  push word [bx+4]
    # Push the offset part
  push word [bx]
    # Load all registers with the desired values
  # TODO: Ensure all registers have the correct values
    # Enter the interrupt
  retf
```

Before the `retf` the stack will look like this:

```
Address (IP) of the interrupt routine
Segment (CS) of the interrupt routine
Address (IP) of the instruction after "call helper"
Segment (CS) of the program
Flags
...
```

The `retf` instruction will behave the same way as if the first two words have been pushed by the "far" `call` instruction: It will remove the first two words from the stack and jump to the address described by these two words - this means: Into the interrupt handler.

At the end of the interrupt handler, the last 3 words will be popped from the stack and the execution will continue at the instruction after `call helper`.

**In 16-bit "Real Mode" with self-modifying code:**

This is quite simple:

```
    # AL contains the interrupt number
    # Modify the "int" instruction, so "int 42" becomes
    # "int 31" if the value of AL is 31.
  mov cs:[theIntInstruction+1], al
    # Load all registers with the desired values
  # TODO: Ensure all registers have the correct values
    # Now perform the "int" instruction
theIntInstruction:
  int 42
```

Self-modifying code can have negative side-effects. This means there can be problems...

**In (16- or 32-bit) "Protected Mode":**

Depending on the memory protection settings you have the chance to write to memory which is "executable". In this case you might use self-modifying code.

If you don't have the possibility to use self-modifying code, it is not possible to perform the equivalent of `int al` unless you want to do the following:

```
performInt0:
    int 0
    ret
performInt1:
    int 1
    ret
performInt2:
    int 2
    ret
...
performInt255:
    int 255
    ret
```

... and then perform a `call` to the desired label.

This is of course always possible.

Comment: In the helper function, after computing bx and setting ds, why not do `jmp far [bx]`?

Comment: @prl Of course, `jmp far [bx]` would also be possible if the interrupt service routine does not require `ds`, `es` and `bx` to have certain values. The variant I was posting allows all registers to have any value - using `iret` instead of `retf` it is even possible to load the flags with the desired values.

Comment: Martin, of course, thanks. I had completely overlooked the comments in the code indicating that.

Answer (score 2):

**There are no good / simple options for the general case, don't do this.**  You'd need self-modifying code, or a jump table with every option, or a chain of conditional branches if there are only a few possible values.

(However, if you only need this to work in real mode, see Martin's answer; emulate `int` with `pushf` and a `call far [ivt_entry]`)

If you're trying to make a wrapper function, don't; make it a macro so it can inline with the interrupt number as a constant.  Or make separate wrappers for every interrupt number you want to use.

Comment: Thanks! The situation is a bit complicated so I guess I will try self-modifying code.

Comment: Actually do you know how I should make an int self-modifying code?

Comment: Check the encoding of`int`.  The first byte is the opcode and the second is the interrupt number.  Overwrite this to change what interrupt you invoke.

Comment: Isn't `pushf ; call far [idt-entry]` a pretty good / simple option? (Similar to Martin's answer.)

Comment: @prl: I hadn't thought of emulating `int` since that's only possible in real mode, which I normally don't use.

Comment: Peter, I realized later that you must be thinking of protected mode. I hadn’t been thinking about protected mode because who uses software interrupts in protected mode, other than the single one used to do a system call.

Comment: @prl: I knew the OP wanted to run this in real mode, I just hadn't thought of even trying to do it any way other than running an `int` instruction.  I meant that normally `int` does things that can't be emulated, but in real mode that's not true; or for whatever reason it just didn't occur to me.  So my answer was premature.  I still don't see why you'd want to do this, especially for a beginner, so I also wasn't thinking too hard about how to make it happen.